# Stepping into .Net framework4.6 source VS 2013

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, pdb-files, .net-4.6

I am trying to step into the .Net source code. I have followed the instruction [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html), the "Microsoft symbol server" is unchecked and I have specified the symbol cache directory. In the module window, the symbol status are "symbols loaded".
For example, when I try to step into the *sort* method 
`List<string> lisTest = new List<string>();
lisTest.Add("b");
lisTest.Add("a");
lisTest.Sort();`

I have "mscorlib.pdb" loaded, but it doesn't step into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of .Net 4.6, it was RC.`.pdb`.Net sources are just available for RTMs. Checking the the "Microsoft symbol server" doesn't matter.